# How do I stop my turtles from stacking up on NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

How do I stop my turtles from stacking up on NetLogo?

I need my turtles to move, but not on top of each other and stop piling up.

I already tried with the following code:

```
to go ask turtles [ let empty-patches neighbors with [not any? turtles-here]

if (breed = ricos)  [
 face one-of patches with [ price = 1000 ]
 if any? empty-patches  [
  fd 1 ]
  ]
 if (breed = pobres) [
 face one-of patches with [ price = 1000 ]
 if any? empty-patches [
 fd 1 ]
 ]
   if (breed = medias)[
     if any? empty-patches [
  face one-of patches with [ price = 1000 ]
 fd 1]

]
]

end

to move-to-empty-one-of [locations]

  move-to one-of locations
  while [any? other turtles-here] [
    move-to one-of locations
  ]
end
```

But they are still piling up.

Comment: Are you ending up with turtles all the way down?

Answer (score 3):

welcome to Stack Overflow! It is often helpful to provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code so that it is easily reproducible- that will increase the chance that you will get a useful answer.

If you have set up your turtles into breeds(`breed [ ricos rico ]`), you can just say `ask ricos [ ...`

Do you call your `move-to-empty-one-of [locations]` procedure somewhere? It is not called in the example code, and so that procedure, which might help turtles from stacking, is not running.

One note- your code says something like:
- Empty patches are neighbor patches without turtles
- Face one of the patches with price 1000
- If there are any empty patches, move forward 1

The problem with that is that `neighbors` includes the 8 empty cells surrounding the current turtle. So, when you say `if any? empty-patches [ ...`, there will likely be at least one empty patch, so the turtle can almost always move forward. Here is an alternative approach that might work for you:

```
breed [ ricos rico ]
patches-own [ price ]

to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks

  ask n-of 20 patches [ 
    set price 1000
    set pcolor grey + 2
  ]
  create-ricos 20 [
    set color random 3 + 63
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end


to go

  ask ricos [
    ifelse [price] of patch-here != 1000 or any? other turtles-here [
      let target min-one-of patches with [ price = 1000 and not any? turtles-here ] [ distance myself]
      face target
      fd 1
    ]
    [
      move-to patch-here
    ]
  ]
  tick 
end
```

This works by having the ricos (in this example) check if they are at a patch with the `price` not equal to 1000 or at a patch with other turtles present. If they are, they will face the nearest patch with `price = 1000` and with no turtle on that patch. Then, they will move toward that patch. If another turtle beats them there, they will re-evaluate and face a new patch that fulfills those conditions.

Comment: I tried to make my turtles (and the 3 respective breeds I have in my model) to go to patches price = 1000 [ target ]. I wanted to make impossible to another turtle move to the same patch that other turtle is,  once my first turtle get to the target I wanted it to stay and not move again.

Comment: I'm trying the following code:                                                                       
 to go

  ask turtles [
    ifelse [price] of patch-here != 1000 or any? other turtles-here [
      let target min-one-of patches with [ price = 1000 and not any? turtles-here ] [ distance myself]
      face target
      fd 1
    ]
    [
      move-to patch-here
    ]
  ]

Comment: And did that give you an error? What was the problem with that code? In my example code i believe the turtles do as you say.